# Mongo aggregration query in foreach loop

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to execute the mongo query mentioned below, but it does not print any value.
However, the aggregation query for a single collection works fine, that is when the foreach loop is not used.

could someone help with this.

Thanks

```
db = db.getSiblingDB("database_test");
var col = ["col1","col2"];
col.forEach(function(col_name){
   db.getCollection(col_name).aggregate(
        [
            {
                "$group" : {
                    "_id" : null,
                    "max" : {
                        "$max" : {
                            "$bsonSize" : "$$ROOT"
                        }
                    },
                    "min" : {
                        "$min" : {
                            "$bsonSize" : "$$ROOT"
                        }
                    },
                    "avg" : {
                        "$avg" : {
                            "$bsonSize" : "$$ROOT"
                        }
                    },
                    "total" : {
                        "$sum" : {
                            "$bsonSize" : "$$ROOT"
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
            ,{
                "$project" : {
                    "_id" : 0.0,
                    "max" : 1.0,
                    "min" : 1.0,
                    "avg" : 1.0,
                    "total_size" : "$total",
                    "record_count" : {
                        "$divide" : [
                            "$total",
                            "$avg"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ], 
        {
            "allowDiskUse" : false
        }
        );
});
```

Comment: use a for loop instead of a foreach and do an `await db.getCollection(col_name)..`. i hope this code is inside an async function

Comment: @cmgchess, I changed the code to for loop, but output comes only for the last item in the array. I tried to add await, but it was throwing error.